# Getting the drop location in a TFS build in the Post-build or AfterBuild event

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm trying to kick off an .exe from my post-build event in a C# project and I don't seem to have access to the `TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION` environment variable.

I'm running the build from TFS as a manually kicked off build and in the project's properties window I've pasted the following code into the Post-build event window: `BuildExe.exe $(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION)`.

The exe (BuildExe.exe) is being kicked off but the parameter is empty. Any idea why? Do I need to kick off this .exe in some other way to have access to the environment variable? I've also tried editing the projects .csproj file and adding the following code to the AfterBuild target and that doesn't work either.

See my code below - the file test2.txt gets created, but it's contents are simply:

```
team build =

team drop location =

    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <WriteLinesToFile File="test2.txt" Lines="@(MyItems)" Overwrite="true"     Encoding="Unicode" />
      </Target>
      <ItemGroup>
        <MyItems Include="team build = $(TF_BUILD)"/>
        <MyItems Include="team drop location = $(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION)"/>
      </ItemGroup>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to say that Team Foundation Environment variables don't work in Post/Pre build events. It is allowed to use macros in the build events, you can check this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.110).aspx) for the macros list.

Instead of using Pre/Post build event, I think you need to choose Build Definition -> Process -> **Post/Pre-build-script** to run your script. And at this time, yon use TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION environment variable in your script. Check this link for the details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn376353(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the Post-Build script arguments when I edit my build definitions. I don't know if it's because I'm running VS2012, but my build defintion looks different from what's pictured in your second link.

Comment: Yes, you're right that Post/Pre-build-script is available in TFS2013, but not in TFS2012. Without using Post/Pre-build-script, you need to use InvokeProcess activity to run your script, you can use TFS build environment variables in your script. Check this blog for the details how to work with InvokeProcess activity: http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2011/03/31/TFS-Build-Invoke-Process-Activity.aspx